# PHP passing argument to a function inside preg_replace

Tags: php, html, regex, string

Hi I have something like this:

```
$content = preg_replace('#(\s*)\<pre(.*?)\>(.*?)\</pre\>(\s*)#sie', 'dostuff(\'\\3\', \'\\2\', $content, \'\', \'\\1\', \'\\4\');', $content);
```

and

```
$content = preg_replace('#(\s*)\<code(.*?)\>(.*?)\</code\>(\s*)#sie', 'dostuff(\'\\3\', \'\\2\', $content, \'\', \'\\1\', \'\\4\');', $content);
```

How can I pass a true/false argument to the dostuff function inside, depending on the element that's being regexed? If it's `<pre>` to be true, and if it's `<code>` to be false?

Comment: ***This is UNBELIEVABLY insecure!***

Comment: the code I posted or what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Your code. As a rule of thumb: Never use the `e`-modifier or `eval`. There are exceptions, but they are rare. Right now I could do a simple `<code>', eval(My code goes here), '</code>` and would have a nice arbitrary-code-execution console for your site ;)

Comment: I have a excuse: I didn't write it :) I'm trying to create a simple syntax highlighter for my site and this is what I found trough google so far

Comment: Why not to use preg_match_all() to get all metches and than working with result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `(pre|code)` in your regexp? You would be able to use `$n` or `\n` reference to name of the HTML tag and use it as a dostuff()'s argument.